# Search for duplicates in separate folders

Tags: windows-search, duplicate

I need to find duplicates (to delete) in two separate directories, and I was wondering if I could create a search function somehow to look for duplicate files.

I could find them by copy/pasting one directory into another, but there are multiple sub-folders, and this process can be messy and sometimes unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that I know is a program called ccleaner, it has a duplicate file finder built in. you can also do a search for duplicate file finder.

here is a list: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_duplicate_file_finders

you can run a scan on one directory so be sure to choose C drive or %SystemDrive% to get everything.